# Error: "Last step of Pipeline should implement fit or be the string 'passthrough'

Tags: python

I've created a Pipeline that was supposed to fit different models to my data and score itself, but instead I've received this error.

The code is as follows:

```
    `models = {"Ridge": Ridge(), 
         "SVR_linear": SVR(kernel="linear"),
         "SVR_rbf": SVR(kernel="rbf"),
         "RandomForestRegressor": RandomForestRegressor()}
reg_results = {}`

`for model_name, model in models.items(): 
    
    # Model preprocessor with pipeline
    model_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), 
                                     ("model", models)])
    
    # Fit models
    print(f"Fitting {model_name}...")
    model_pipeline.fit(car_X_train, car_y_train)
    
    # Score model and append model results dict with values
    print(f"Scoring {model_name}...")
    reg_results[model_name] = model.pipeline.score(car_X_test, car_y_test)`
```

Comment: You assign `models` to your pipeline, not `model`.

Answer (score 1):

```
model_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), 
                                     ("model", model)])
```

replace **"models"** with **"model"**;

- because **"models"** is your model dictionary,
- and you shuould use your dictionary values in this Pipeline steps (**"model"** from your *for loop*)